# pandas columns correlation with statistical significance

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, correlation

What is the best way, given a pandas dataframe, df, to get the correlation between its columns `df.1` and `df.2`?

I do not want the output to count rows with `NaN`, which `pandas` built-in correlation does. But I also want it to output a `pvalue` or a standard error, which the built-in does not.

`SciPy` seems to get caught up by the NaNs, though I believe it does report significance.

Data example:

```
     1           2
0    2          NaN
1    NaN         1
2    1           2
3    -4          3
4    1.3         1
5    NaN         NaN
```

Comment: could you provide an example of your data?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answer provided by @Shashank is nice. However, if you want a solution in pure `pandas`, you may like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
from datetime import datetime
import scipy.stats  as stats


gdp = pd.DataFrame(DataReader("GDP", "fred", start=datetime(1990, 1, 1)))
vix = pd.DataFrame(DataReader("VIXCLS", "fred", start=datetime(1990, 1, 1)))

#Do it with a pandas regression to get the p value from the F-test
df = gdp.merge(vix,left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
vix_on_gdp = pd.ols(y=df['VIXCLS'], x=df['GDP'], intercept=True)
print(df['VIXCLS'].corr(df['GDP']), vix_on_gdp.f_stat['p-value'])
```

Results:

```
-0.0422917932738 0.851762475093
```

Same results as stats function:

```
#Do it with stats functions. 
df_clean = df.dropna()
stats.pearsonr(df_clean['VIXCLS'], df_clean['GDP'])
```

Results:

```
  (-0.042291793273791969, 0.85176247509284908)
```

To extend to more vairables I give you an ugly loop based approach:

```
#Add a third field
oil = pd.DataFrame(DataReader("DCOILWTICO", "fred", start=datetime(1990, 1, 1))) 
df = df.merge(oil,left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')

#construct two arrays, one of the correlation and the other of the p-vals
rho = df.corr()
pval = np.zeros([df.shape[1],df.shape[1]])
for i in range(df.shape[1]): # rows are the number of rows in the matrix.
    for j in range(df.shape[1]):
        JonI        = pd.ols(y=df.icol(i), x=df.icol(j), intercept=True)
        pval[i,j]  = JonI.f_stat['p-value']
```

Results of rho:

```
             GDP    VIXCLS  DCOILWTICO
 GDP         1.000000 -0.042292    0.870251
 VIXCLS     -0.042292  1.000000   -0.004612
 DCOILWTICO  0.870251 -0.004612    1.000000
```

Results of pval:

```
 [[  0.00000000e+00   8.51762475e-01   1.11022302e-16]
  [  8.51762475e-01   0.00000000e+00   9.83747425e-01]
  [  1.11022302e-16   9.83747425e-01   0.00000000e+00]]
```

Comment: What if there are more than 2 columns, is there a way to get a nice output table for correlations?

Comment: df.corr() will give you the correlation structure for the whole data frame but to use the regression calculation approach of the p-value would be messy.

Comment: `pd.ols` was deprecated in v 0.20.0, and `DataReader` was moved to `pandas-datareader`: https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader

Answer (score 60):

To calculate **all the p-values at once**, you can use **`calculate_pvalues` function** (code below):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[2,5,3], 'C':[5,2,1], 'D':['text',2,3] })
calculate_pvalues(df)
```

The output is **similar to the `corr()`** (but with p-values):

```
            A       B       C
    A       0  0.7877  0.1789
    B  0.7877       0  0.6088
    C  0.1789  0.6088       0
```

---

***Details:***

- **Column D is automatically ignored** as it contains text.
- p-values are **rounded to 4 decimals**
- You can subset to indicate exact columns: `calculate_pvalues(df[['A','B','C']]`

---

#### Following is the ***code of the function***:

```
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
import pandas as pd

def calculate_pvalues(df):
    dfcols = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
    pvalues = dfcols.transpose().join(dfcols, how='outer')
    for r in df.columns:
        for c in df.columns:
            tmp = df[df[r].notnull() & df[c].notnull()]
            pvalues[r][c] = round(pearsonr(tmp[r], tmp[c])[1], 4)
    return pvalues
```

Answer (score 49):

Statistical significance denoted in asterisks:

```
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
import numpy as np
rho = df.corr()
pval = df.corr(method=lambda x, y: pearsonr(x, y)[1]) - np.eye(*rho.shape)
p = pval.applymap(lambda x: ''.join(['*' for t in [.05, .01, .001] if x<=t]))
rho.round(2).astype(str) + p
```

[image: Correlations with asterisks]

Comment: This is great for implementing. Any chance that it can be worked into a sns.heatmap with np.triu as mask?

Comment: Note that the intervals for attributing an asterix are not correct. it should be: [0.001, 0.01, 0.05]
source: https://faq.edqm.eu/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1377305

Comment: Corrected the interval numbers @Moritz pointed out.

Answer (score 32):

You can use the [scipy.stats](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/stats.html) correlation functions to get the p-value.

For example, if you are looking for a correlation such as pearson correlation, you can use the [pearsonr](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html#scipy.stats.pearsonr) function.

```
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
pearsonr([1, 2, 3], [4, 3, 7])
```

Gives output

```
(0.7205766921228921, 0.48775429164459994)
```

Where the first value in the tuple is the correlation value, and second is the p-value.

In your case, you can use pandas' `dropna` function to remove `NaN` values first.

```
df_clean = df[['column1', 'column2']].dropna()
pearsonr(df_clean['column1'], df_clean['column2'])
```

Answer (score 23):

In pandas v0.24.0 a `method` argument was added to `corr`. Now, you can use it to compute arbitrary functions, e.g. the p-value:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[2,5,3], 'C':[5,2,1]})

# this computes the correlation coefficients
corr = df.corr(method=lambda x, y: pearsonr(x, y)[0]) 

# this computes the p-values
pvalues = df.corr(method=lambda x, y: pearsonr(x, y)[1]) - np.eye(len(df.columns)) 
pvalues
```

```py
          A         B         C
A  0.000000  0.787704  0.178912
B  0.787704  0.000000  0.608792
C  0.178912  0.608792  0.000000
```

Please note the workaround with `np.eye(len(df.columns))` for the p-values, which is needed, because self-correlations are always set to `1.0` (see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25726).

Comment: Sorry, where is 'p value' in your answer?

Comment: I just updated the answer. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to sum the logic in a function, it might not be the most efficient approach but will provide you with a similar output as pandas df.corr(). To use this just put the following function in your code and call it providing your dataframe object ie. *corr_pvalue(your_dataframe)*.

I have rounded the values to 4 decimal place, in case you want different output please change the value in round function.

```
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def corr_pvalue(df):


    numeric_df = df.dropna()._get_numeric_data()
    cols = numeric_df.columns
    mat = numeric_df.values

    arr = np.zeros((len(cols),len(cols)), dtype=object)

    for xi, x in enumerate(mat.T):
        for yi, y in enumerate(mat.T[xi:]):
            arr[xi, yi+xi] = map(lambda _: round(_,4), pearsonr(x,y))
            arr[yi+xi, xi] = arr[xi, yi+xi]

    return pd.DataFrame(arr, index=cols, columns=cols)
```

I have tested it with pandas v0.18.1

Answer (score 1):

That was very useful code by **oztalha**. I just changed formatting (rounded to 2 digits) wherever r was not significant.

```
    rho = data.corr()
    pval = calculate_pvalues(data) # toto_tico's answer
    # create three masks
    r1 = rho.applymap(lambda x: '{:.2f}*'.format(x))
    r2 = rho.applymap(lambda x: '{:.2f}**'.format(x))
    r3 = rho.applymap(lambda x: '{:.2f}***'.format(x))
    r4 = rho.applymap(lambda x: '{:.2f}'.format(x))
    # apply them where appropriate --this could be a single liner
    rho = rho.mask(pval>0.1,r4)
    rho = rho.mask(pval<=0.1,r1)
    rho = rho.mask(pval<=0.05,r2)
    rho = rho.mask(pval<=0.01,r3)
    rho
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 1):

Great answers from @toto_tico and @Somendra-joshi.
However, it drops unnecessary NAs values. In this snippet, I'm just dropping the NAs that belong to the correlation being computing at the moment. In the actual [corr implementation](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.3/pandas/core/frame.py#L6482-L6536), they do the same.

```
def calculate_pvalues(df):
    df = df._get_numeric_data()
    dfcols = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
    pvalues = dfcols.transpose().join(dfcols, how='outer')
    for r in df.columns:
        for c in df.columns:
            if c == r:
                df_corr = df[[r]].dropna()
            else:
                df_corr = df[[r,c]].dropna()
            pvalues[r][c] = pearsonr(df_corr[r], df_corr[c])[1]
    return pvalues
```

Answer (score 0):

In a single line of code using list comprehension:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from scipy.stats import pearsonr
>>> data = {'y':[0, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 5, 7, 6],
...         'x1':[0, 4, 2, 6, 2, 8, 6, 10, 4, 13, 5],
...         'x2':[0.0, 1.3, 0.2, 4.5, 1.3, 1.6, 3.5, 1.7, 1.6, 3.7, 1.7]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> pvals = pd.DataFrame([[pearsonr(df[c], df[y])[1] for y in df.columns] for c in df.columns],
...                      columns=df.columns, index=df.columns)
>>> pvals
           y        x1        x2
y   0.000000  0.000732  0.069996
x1  0.000732  0.000000  0.036153
x2  0.069996  0.036153  0.000000
>>>
```

Comment: Not exactly slick, but this works and gets the desired output,
p = pd.DataFrame([[pearsonr(df[c], df[y])[1] for y in df.columns] for c in df.columns],
                      columns=df.columns, index=df.columns).copy()
p["type"] = "p"
p.index.name="col"
p = p.set_index([p.index,"type"])

c = df.corr()
c["type"] = "c"
c.index.name = "col"
c = c.set_index([c.index,"type"])

c.combine_first(p)