# pandas correlation with statistical significance returning: (nan, 1.0)

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, pearson-correlation

I would like to check the correlation and the significance of the correlation between multiple columns in a pandas dataframe.

With the following dataframe, I have constructed the following correlation table:

```
      ARI     Flesch    Kincaid       time  VIX_close  FEDFUNDS  
-2.090000        NaN  -3.400000 2016-02-04  20.239333  0.345333      
16.060272  38.489788  14.355616 2016-02-04  20.239333  0.345333
```

[image: Correlation Table]

And when I run Kincaid versus other variables using the following code everything works out fine:

```
stats.pearsonr(master.Kincaid,master.VIX_close)
```

However, when I run similar code for other variables:

```
stats.pearsonr(master.ARI,master.VIX_close)
```

I get the following output:

```
(nan, 1.0)
```

I understand that if the variance of ARI this output would be understandable, however this is not the case -- ARI is very similar to Kincaid...

Bonus Question: is there anyway to run a significance test across the entire correlation table in one go?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Huh?  Only ARI & Kincaid have any variation here so nothing else has variance.  I mean, you are showing only 2 rows of data and most have the same value so not sure what you expect.  If you have more data, you should show it.  If you have 1,000 rows, don't show 1,000 but maybe 5 to 10 rows of data.

Comment: The data does vary, I only put two rows to show the format of my dataframe...

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a built-in correlation function to run against the whole dataframe

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html

Maybe just run master.corr()

Calculate for all combinations:

```
import itertools
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind, pearsonr
columns_combinations = [c for c in itertools.combinations(master.columns,2)]
pearson_calc_df = pd.DataFrame([pearsonr(master[c[0]], master[c[1]]) for c in columns_combinations], 
                               index=columns_combinations)
ttest_calc_df = pd.DataFrame([ttest_ind(master[c[0]], master[c[1]]) for c in columns_combinations], 
                              index=columns_combinations)
```

You will still have the NaN on correlation as the variance is zero though.

Comment: Thanks, that what I used to make the correlation table but is there a way to test for significance too?

Comment: @GrahamStreich Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25571882/pandas-columns-correlation-with-statistical-significance