# How to find the correlation between categories of the same column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, heatmap, correlation, categorical-data

How can I generate a correlation matrix of different categories in the same column? I am working with medical data in which I have a column with different categories of diseases assigned to different patients. For eg,

```
    patient disease 
1    101      A   
2    101      B  
3    102      A     
4    102      C   
5    102      B
6    103      A   
7    104      B  
8    104      C
```

I want to find the correlation between the different diseases A, B, and C to find out if a patient has disease A, how likely they will have disease B, and so on for every pair.

Something like this,

```
     A     B     C 
A   ...   ...   ...
B   ...   ...   ...
C   ...   ...   ...
```

Comment: do you want a pairwise correlation ?

Comment: Does it answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25571882/pandas-columns-correlation-with-statistical-significance

Comment: @Corralien not really. As i just need to get a pairwise correlation of the categories A, B, C

Comment: @AminS yes the pairwise correlation

Comment: @Corralien, any idea how this correlation can be achieved?

Comment: i know it's easy but your data structure needs some manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `pivot_table` for that manner.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'patient': [101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 103, 104, 104], 
        'disease': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C']})
pivot_table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='patient', index='disease', columns='disease', aggfunc='count',fill_value = 0)
# set fill_value to 0 in case of no combination between 2 diseases
correlation_matrix = pivot_table.corr() # Initialize corr matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

well this approach is based on some restructuring of the data and it works.

```
import pandas as pd

data_main = {'patient':[101,101,102,102,102,103,104,104],'disease':['A','B','A','C','B','A','B','C']}

new_data_main = [] #adding columns for every unique values of disease

df = pd.DataFrame(new_data_main)

len_data = len(data_main['patient'])
checked = [] #prevent duplicate 
for j in data_main['patient']:
    if j in checked:
        continue
    indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(data_main['patient']) if x == j]
    temp_data = {'patient':j,'A':0,'B':0,'C':0}
    for k in indices:
        str_dis = data_main['disease'][k]
        temp_data[str_dis]=1
    checked.append(j)
    new_data_main.append(temp_data)


df = pd.DataFrame(new_data_main)


print(df.corr())
'''
          patient         A         B         C
patient  1.000000 -0.774597 -0.258199  0.447214
A       -0.774597  1.000000 -0.333333 -0.577350
B       -0.258199 -0.333333  1.000000  0.577350
C        0.447214 -0.577350  0.577350  1.000000
'''
```

Comment: Thank you. I am not clear about the `temp_data` part. I have a large dataframe similar to the sample data that I have mentioned. So, how should I do it in this case since I can't assign zeros to the diseases manually

Comment: put it in a for loop for your key list then equal  it to zero.  u can create that list of unique values of diseases column by drop_duplicate() or unique() method. both work in pandas.